# Create Png by sending json to php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to make an app where users can crop the image then save then can download it, but after cropping when i click on save button the png image created is of 0kb... 
what could be the error?

this is my js file

```
function getIndex(e) {
    var t = c.getObjects();
    for (var n in t) {
        if (t[n] == e) {
            return n
        }
    }
}

function loadingShow(e) {
    $("#overlay_loading").show();
    $("#overlay_loading #load_message").html(e);
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden")
}

function loadingHide() {
    $("#overlay_loading").hide();
    $("body").css("overflow", "inherit")
}

function getData() {
    var e = $("body").data("dats")
}

function reloadThumbs(e) {
    if (!cropping) {
        var t = $($("#object_layers li").get().reverse());
        if (e) {
            var n = [];
            var r = getIndex(e);
            n[r] = e
        } else {
            var n = c.getObjects();
            var i = "";
            if (n.length !== t.length) {
                $("#object_layers").empty();
                for (var s = 0; s < n.length; s++) {
                    var o = $('<image width="120" height="75" />').attr("src", i);
                    $("<li/>").prependTo("#object_layers").append(o)
                }
                t = $($("#object_layers li").get().reverse())
            }
        }
        for (s in n) {
            if (n[s] !== undefined) {
                var u = fabric.document.createElement("canvas");
                if (!u.getContext && typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != "undefined") {
                    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(u)
                }
                u.width = $("#cc").width();
                u.height = $("#cc").height();
                fabric.util.wrapElement(u, "div");
                var a = new fabric.Canvas(u);
                a.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                var f = n[s].isActive();
                a.add(n[s]);
                a.renderAll();
                var i = a.toDataURLWithMultiplier("png", .35101058);
                if (f) {}
                $(t.get(s)).find("img").attr("src", i);
                $("#object_layers li").click(function () {
                    $("#object_layers li").removeClass("layer_selected");
                    $(this).addClass("layer_selected")
                })
            }
        }
        reloadData()
    }
}

function reloadLayers() {
    $($("#object_layers li").get().reverse()).each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("object") !== undefined) c.bringToFront($(this).data("object"))
    });
    reloadData()
}

function reloadData() {
    var e = c.getObjects();
    var t = $($("#object_layers li").get().reverse());
    for (var n in e) {
        if (e[n] !== undefined) {
            $(t.get(n)).data("object", e[n])
        }
    }
    c.selection = false
}

function cropStart() {
    cropping = true;
    c.forEachObject(function (e) {
        e.selectable = false
    });
    var e = actObj;
    var t = {
        left: 450,
        top: 150,
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    };
    console.log(t);
    cropObject = new Crop({
        left: t.left,
        top: t.top,
        fill: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        width: t.width,
        height: t.height
    });
    c.add(cropObject);
    c.deactivateAll();
    cropObject.selectable = true;
    c.setActiveObject(cropObject);
    c.bringToFront(cropObject);
    c.renderAll();
    $("#crop_control").show()
}

function crop() {
    var e = cropObject.width * cropObject.scaleX;
    var t = cropObject.height * cropObject.scaleY;
    var n = cropObject.left - e / 2;
    var r = cropObject.top - t / 2;
    var i = actObj;
    i.clone(function (s) {
        var o = fabric.document.createElement("canvas");
        if (!o.getContext && typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != "undefined") {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(o)
        }
        o.width = e;
        o.height = t;
        fabric.util.wrapElement(o, "div");
        var u = new fabric.Canvas(o);
        u.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        s.setOpacity(1);
        u.add(s);
        s.left -= n;
        s.top -= r;
        u.renderAll();
        var a = u.toDataURL();
        var f = $("<img src=" + a + " />").get(0);
        i.scaleX = 1;
        i.scaleY = 1;
        i.setElement(f);
        i.width = e;
        i.height = t;
        i.setAngle(0);
        c.setActiveObject(i);
        c.renderAll();
        setTimeout(function () {
            c.renderAll();
            reloadThumbs(i)
        }, 100);
        reloadThumbs()
    });
    cropFinish()
}

function cropFinish() {
    $("#crop_control").hide();
    $(".ct").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#object_layers").sortable("enable");
    cropping = false;
    c.remove(cropObject);
    cropObject = null
}
var cropping = false;
var c = new fabric.Canvas("cc");
var start, set = "personal";
c.setOverlayImage("img/foreground-personal.png", c.renderAll.bind(c));
c.backgroundColor = "rgba(59,89,152,1)";
$(function () {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {} else {}
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        add: function (e, t) {
            if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
                $(t.files).each(function (e) {
                    var t = this;
                    var n = new FileReader;
                    n.onload = function (e) {
                        var t = e.target.result;
                        fabric.Image.fromURL(t, function (e) {
                            if (e.getWidth() > 800) {
                                e.scaleToWidth(800)
                            }
                            if (e.getHeight() > 400) {
                                e.scaleToHeight(400)
                            }
                            c.add(e);
                            e.setActive(true);
                            c.centerObjectH(e).centerObjectV(e);
                            e.setCoords();
                            c.renderAll();
                            var n = $('<image width="120" height="55" />').attr("src", t);
                            $("<li/>").prependTo("#object_layers").append(n);
                            reloadThumbs()
                        })
                    };
                    n.readAsDataURL(t)
                })
            } else {
                t.submit()
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, t) {
            $.each(t.result, function (e, t) {
                $("<p/>").text(t.name).appendTo(document.body);
                fabric.Image.fromURL(t.url, function (e) {
                    var t = e.set({
                        left: 110,
                        top: 75
                    }).scale(.7);
                    c.add(t).renderAll()
                })
            })
        }
    });
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 46 && !cropping) {
            var t = c.getActiveObject();
            if (t) {
                c.remove(t);
                reloadThumbs()
            }
        }
    });
    $("#save").click(function () {
        var e = JSON.stringify(c);
        loadingShow("Saving... Please Wait...");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                d: e
            }
        }).done(function (e) {
            loadingHide();
            alert("Data Saved!")
        })
    })
});
c.observe("object:modified", function (e) {
    reloadThumbs(e.target)
});
c.observe("object:selected", function (e) {
    var t = e.target;
    var n = getIndex(t);
    if (t.type == "image") {
        $(".ot").attr("disabled", "disabled").val("");
        $(".oi").removeAttr("disabled")
    } else if (t.type == "text") {
        $(".oi").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".ot").removeAttr("disabled");
        var r = t.toObject();
        var i = t.getFill();
        if (start && r.text == "Click here to start") {
            c.clear();
            reloadThumbs();
            start = false
        }
        $("#text_text").val(r.text);
        $("#text_color").val(i.toUpperCase());
        $("#text_font").val(r.fontFamily)
    }
});
c.observe("selection:cleared", function (e) {
    $(".ot").val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".oi").val("").attr("disabled", "disabled")
});
var cropObject = null;
var actObj;
$("#image_crop").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".ct").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#object_layers").sortable("disable");
    actObj = c.getActiveObject();
    cropStart();
    return false
});
$("#crop_ok").click(function () {
    crop();
    c.forEachObject(function (e) {
        e.selectable = true
    })
});
$("#crop_cancel").click(function () {
    cropping = false;
    cropFinish();
    c.setActiveObject(actObj);
    c.forEachObject(function (e) {
        e.selectable = true
    });
    return false
})
```

this is the save code in js using ajax

```
$("#save").click(function () {
            var e = JSON.stringify(c);
            loadingShow("Saving... Please Wait...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {
                    d: e
                }
            }).done(function (e) {
                loadingHide();
                alert("Data Saved!")
            })
        })
    });
```

this my  php file

```
echo $_POST['e'];
echo json_decode($_POST['e']);
echo var_dump(json_decode($_POST['e']));
$name=time();
file_put_contents("uploads/" . $name . ".png", $data);
```

Comment: Did you research this at all, or did you find a problem with your code and bring it here expecting us to fix it for you and send you on your happy merry little way? Please present what you tried so we can elaborate as to why it might not be working.

Comment: What function is called when you click save?...What is your HTML like...? How can we help if we don't even know what is being called on save?

Comment: i have tried to crop the image in the canvas and to save it.. but the image generated when saved in server is 0kb

Comment: Where is $_POST['e'] being set?

Comment: $_POST['e'] is set in ajax.php

Comment: Lol, dude. Can you add all of the relevant code so we can determine what's wrong?

Comment: i added all the codes

Answer (score 1):

Your posted data has a key `d` but you are trying to read from `e` which doesn't have a value.

Even if that wasn't the case, then I'm pretty sure that no valid JSON data will decode to be a PNG binary anyway.

Comment: when i read from 'd' the image is not getting generated. its is keep on loading like "saving please wait"

Comment: then what will be valid json data?